# I can't find where the issue is in my code,my delete function is deleting everything in the state but is not deleting a customer in the database

Tags: reactjs

I can't find where the issue is in my code,my delete function is deleting everything in the state but is not deleting a customer in the database.Can someone tell me where the issue is? I checked on my HTTP route and it seems fine. I also tried removing all the conditions to see if it works but it deletes all the records in the view but not in the database.Am I missing something?Thanks.

`This is my delete function code:`

```
    deleteCustomer(id){
    let confirmDeletion = window.confirm('Do you really wish to delete it?');
    if (confirmDeletion) {

        fetch('api/Customer/Delete/' + id, {
            method:'delete'
            })
            .then(data => {
            this.setState(
                {
                    cusList: this.state.cusList.filter((rec) => {
                        return (rec.customerId != id);
                    })
                });
        });
    }
    }
```

`This is my render where all the data is deleted when a delete button of one customer is clicked`
`and then displays"No customers yet":`

```
    renderCustomerTable = (cusList) => {
    return (
        <table className="ui celled fixed single line table">
            <thead className="">
                <tr className="">
                    <th className="">Name</th>
                    <th className="">Address</th>
                    <th className="">Action</th>
                    <th className="">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody className="">
                {!cusList || cusList.length <=0 ?
                    <tr><td colSpan="6" align="center"><b>No Customers yet</b></td></tr>
                    :this.state.cusList.map(cus =>
                    <tr className="" key={cus.customerId}>
                        <td className="">{cus.name}</td>
                        <td className="">{cus.address}</td>
                        <td className="">
                            <Button className="ui yellow icon left labeled button " ><i aria- 
   hidden="true" class="edit icon"></i>Edit</Button>
                        </td>
                        <td className="">
                            <Button className="ui red icon left labeled button " onClick={(id) => 
    this.deleteCustomer(cus.customerId)}><i aria-hidden="true" class="delete icon"> 
   </i>Delete</Button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                )}
            </tbody>
        </table>);
    }
```

`This is my controller:`

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Customer/Details/{id}")]
    public Customer Details(int id)
    {
        return objcustomer.GetCustomerData(id);
    }
```

`This is my customerdataaccess:`

````
   public int DeleteCustomer(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            Customer cus = db.Customer.Find(id);
            db.Customer.Remove(cus);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return 1;
        }
        catch
        {
         throw;
        }
    }
```
````

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `fetch('api/Customer/Details/' + id,`?

Comment: I have tried this one and it does not work :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 fetch(`/api/Customer/Delete/${id}`, {
        method:'delete'
        })
        .then(data => {
            this.setState(prevState=>({
               cusList: prevState.cusList.filter((rec)=>rec.customerId != id)
            });
    });
```

Comment: It gives the same output :-(

Comment: can you show me your httpDelete router?

it seems that the router youre showing us the one for fetching the data GetCustomerData(id);

Comment: [HttpDelete]
        [Route("api/Customer/Delete/{id}")]
        public int Delete(int id)
        {
            return objcustomer.DeleteCustomer(id);
        }

Comment: i did try replacing the "Details"to Delete but it gives the same output

Comment: [HttpDelete]
        [Route("api/Customer/Delete/{id}")]
        public int Delete(int id)
        {
            return objcustomer.DeleteCustomer(id);
        }